# How can I use onClick

Tags: javascript, reactjs

On the small screen, it doesn't show/hide. How can I change this code to work on the small screen?

```
import React from 'react';
import assets from './assets';
import { FaBars, FaFacebook, FaRegHeart, FaInstagram, FaLinkedin, FaStar, FaStarHalf, FaTimes, FaTwitter } from 'react-icons/fa';
```

```
var navLinks = document.getElementById('navLinks');
function showMenu() {
    navLinks.style.right = "0";
}
function hideMenu() {
    navLinks.style.right = "-200px";
}
```

> Above var worked a few times mistakenly, but I still did not get it.

```
export const Home = () => (
    <>
        <section class="header">
            <nav>
                <a href="/"><img src={assets.logo} alt='Logo' width='100%' /></a>
                <div id='navLinks' class='nav-links'>
                    <FaTimes class='fa' onClick={showMenu} />
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="/">HOME</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/About">ABOUT</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/Course">COURSE</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/Blog">BLOG</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/Contact">CONTACT</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <FaBars class='fa' onClick={hideMenu} />
            </nav>

            <div class="text-box">
                <h1>World's Biggest University</h1>
                <p>Making website is now one of the easiest thing in the world. You just need to learn HTML, CSS,<br />Javascript and you are good to go.</p>
                <a href="/Contact" class="hero-btn">Visit Us to Know More</a>
            </div>
        </section>
    </>
)
```

> My CSS file is below.
> **I've tried many ways but I couldn't.**

```
nav .fa{
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: So what can we do to help? What's not working with the onClick?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, simply 'onClick' or 'var'  is not working for small screens and I try to learn how can I fix it.

Comment: You can't do DOM queries outside of functions in React, check the `useRef()` hook or move your `var navLinks = document.getElementById('navLinks');` in your functions ;)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply, Can you please show me how can I move in my function. I tried but gives an error.

Answer (score 1):

As some people have mentioned before you are not utilising the React library correctly.

The (*untested*) code below should suit you better. As you can see a `state` has been used instead of directly changing style properties. I have tried to comment the code as clearly as possible but for more in depth instructions i recommend reading the React docs.

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import assets from './assets';
import { FaBars, FaFacebook, FaRegHeart, FaInstagram, FaLinkedin, FaStar, FaStarHalf, FaTimes, FaTwitter } from 'react-icons/fa';

export const Home = () => {

    // Set state value to keep track of menu open or closed status
    const [navOpen, setNavOpen] = useState(false)

    // Open the active menu
    const open = () => {
        setNavOpen(true)
    }

    // Close the active menu
    const close = () => {
        setNavOpen(false)
    }

    return (
        <>
            <section class="header">
                <nav>
                    <a href="/"><img src={assets.logo} alt='Logo' width='100%' /></a>
                    <div id='navLinks' class='nav-links'>
                        <button onClick={open}>
                            <FaTimes class='fa' />
                        </button>

                        {
                            // Only render the UL node when the navOpen variable is true
                            navOpen && (
                                <ul>
                                    <li><a href="/">HOME</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="/About">ABOUT</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="/Course">COURSE</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="/Blog">BLOG</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="/Contact">CONTACT</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            )
                        }
                        
                    </div>
                    <button onClick={close}>
                        <FaBars class='fa' />
                    </button>
                </nav>
    
                <div class="text-box">
                    <h1>World's Biggest University</h1>
                    <p>Making website is now one of the easiest thing in the world. You just need to learn HTML, CSS,<br />Javascript and you are good to go.</p>
                    <a href="/Contact" class="hero-btn">Visit Us to Know More</a>
                </div>
            </section>
        </>
    )
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your efforts, still, the menu does not show. The icon appears without any problem but when I click nothing is happening. Again appreciated, indeed.

Comment: This is probably related to a css rule on your nav. My guess would be a display: none. You can remove it. Also make sure the icon components have an onClick prop. Wrapping the icons with a button and setting the onClick functions on it is also a good idea

Comment: I have changed the code above and implemented the button approach.
This will alter your style a bit so change your CSS accordingly.

As mentioned before please double check if you have any css rules hiding your nav and remove them.

Comment: Dear @micheal_koelewijn, I truly appreciate your generous help/assistance. Again it does not work. I did solve it in another way. This theme is only HTML/CSS based, and I'd like to make it as a PWA. And finally did it (https://sweet-dew-2592.on.fleek.co/)